# Adding a string to each section of a single-line file efficiently in Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, while-loop, stream, byte

I have some Powershell code here that allows me to add a string of characters to each section of 500 characters in a single-line text file.

```
[system.io.stream]$stream = [system.io.File]::OpenRead($path)
$number_of_sections = $stream.length / 500
$count = 0
[Byte[]] $section_bytes = New-Object byte[] 500

while($count -lt $number_of_sections) {
        [Void]$stream.Read($section_bytes, 0 ,500)
        $thisLine = [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::ASCII.GetString($section_bytes)

        $section = $thisLine.Substring(0,500)
        $string_to_be_added += "example string" + $section
        $count++
}

[Byte[]] $get_bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($string_to_be_added)
$write_bytes = [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($write_path, $get_bytes)
```

Now this code reads the large, single line in the text file byte by byte. The problem occurs when I try to read and write very large files (60MB and above). This script takes around 30 mins to execute which is way too slow and uses up a lot of memory.

Is there another method or an update to my code which will allow me to process a file quicker and add my string to each 500 char section more efficiently? Thanks.

Comment: The `while` loop makes no changes that last outside the loop until the last iteration, so it doesn't add characters to each section. `ReadAllBytes()` takes a filename as a parameter, there's no way `$string_to_be_added` after the last loop iteration also happens to be a valid (500+ byte) filename. Then you have an undefined `$write_path`. I suspect it takes forever because you never increment `$count` so the loop never quits, and you haven't actually seen it finish and noticed that it doesn't work?

Comment: I edited the code to include the incrementation. I have the $write_path already initialised above that code. I think I need some way to write each segment of my string and the 500 characters every time the loop is executed but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) that handle text files properly
2. Don't accumulate the output, write it immediately

```
#$outputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII
$outputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false), #UTF8 without BOM
$reader = [IO.StreamReader]::new('r:\1.txt')
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::new('r:\2.txt',
                                 $false, # don't append
                                 $outputEncoding,
                                 10MB) # write-back cache
$buf = [char[]]::new(500)

while (!$reader.EndOfStream) {
    $nRead = $reader.Read($buf, 0, $buf.length)
    $writer.Write('example string')
    $writer.Write($buf, 0, $nRead)
}

$reader.Close()
$writer.Close()
```

In case you REALLY need to accumulate the text in a variable to use it afterwards, use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$reader = [IO.StreamReader]::new('r:\1.txt')
$buf = [char[]]::new(500)
$prefix = 'example string'
$outputSize = $reader.BaseStream.Length * (1 + $prefix.Length / 500)
$text = [Text.StringBuilder]::new([int]$outputSize) # allocate memory

while (!$reader.EndOfStream) {
    $nRead = $reader.Read($buf, 0, $buf.length)
    $text.Append($prefix) >$null
    $text.Append($buf, 0, $nRead) >$null
}

$reader.Close()
$newText = $text.ToString()
```

And here's an example of using regexps:

```
$prefix = 'example string'
$prefixRX = $prefix.Replace('$', '$$') # escape special sequences like $& etc.
                                       # see https://msdn.microsoft.com/ewy2t5e0
$prefix + ([IO.File]::ReadAllText('r:\1.txt') -replace '(?s).{500}', ('$&' + $prefixRX)) |
    Out-File 'r:\2.txt' -Encoding utf8
```